# MsTest - XML datasource: can you retrieve the entire XML as XElement?

Tags: xml, datasource, mstest

So, here's the issue.
We're now experimenting with XML directly as a data source like so:

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", 
    @"Datasets\test01.xml", "test", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

My (already existing) test automation framework is completely made to parse and work with test data passed as `XElement` parameters.

However, it seems that using the above code results in a `DataRow` containing a `DataTable` which in turn breaks up the XML structure into its individual subnodes. Also, according to [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4af04813-c160-43c9-90a1-6f271b732762/data-driven-test-embedded-xml?forum=vsunittest), the XML should contain a table (of at most two levels deep)?

All I want to achieve is something like this, but **I'm missing the link between the DataRow and XElement objects**.

```
XElement xmlData = testContext.DataRow["login"];
```

So that from this XML, the `login` element is returned. Edit: this element will itself contain several child nodes (depth can be multiple levels).

```
   <test>
       <login>...</login>
       <actions>...</actions>
   </test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this. However, the issue is that the `DataRow.Table` currently returns the entire XML and not just the supposed current datarow.

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            testContext.DataRow.Table.WriteXml(ms);
            var xmlData = XElement.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
            Console.Write(xmlData.ToString());
            return xmlData.Element(rowName).Element(tag);
        }
```